# How to find bins with specified values after using imhist function?

Tags: matlab

I read an image in matlab using

```
I = imread ('face.jpg');
```

Then I do :

```
h = imhist(I);
```

It gives me the histogram of image with 256 value, but I want to see bins of just some value like `{207,63,124,252,4}`, How can I do that ?

Comment: Well, the bin containing the counts for the pixel value `0` is `h(1)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html):

> `[counts,binLocations] = imhist(I)` returns the histogram counts in
> `counts` and the bin locations in `binLocations` so that
> `stem(binLocations,counts)` shows the histogram. For indexed images,
> `imhist` returns the histogram counts for each colormap entry.

So, if you want the `counts` for only some `binLocations`, you should try to call `imhist` with two output variables, and index `counts` using the desired `binLocations`.

---

<sub>Note: I don't have the Image Processing Toolbox so I can't test this for you.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your help, I do your solution with the below code :

Comment: [counts,binLocations] = imhist(I);
bins = [207 63 124 252 4];

for i=1:length(bins)
 for j=1:length(binLocations)
  if(bins(i) == binLocations(j))
   binCounts(i) == counts(j);
  end;
 end;
end;

stem(bins , binCounts);       am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is already what you are looking for, but have you tried

```
 [h,binLocations] = imhist(I)
```

with binlocations being the vector you are looking for.